# Passing Variable to Batch file from VBs

Tags: vbscript

I want to pass a variable from vbscript to batch file.
I used :

```
shell.run "c.bat D:\d"
```

And c.bat received it as `%1`

i.e `xcopy %1 D:\o\ /E`

This works fine, but actually the path is to be entered by user. So it is saved in a variable say x. How do I pass this variable to the batch file?

Comment: Haven't you already ask the same question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475319/problem-copying-files-through-xcopy-using-vbscript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536695/passing-variable-from-vbscript-to-batch-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543345/passing-variable-to-a-batch-file-when-called-using-call-function? Please do not post duplicate questions. If you need to provide additional information regarding your problem, edit the original post.

Comment: ohk. i thought i will clearly ask the qs again. but i still haven't got the solution. so any help is still very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "c:\path\"
shell.run "c.bat " & x
```

This should run `c.bat c:\path\`